# Check for updates of packages installed through yaourt

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, yaourt

Is there anyway to update package installed with yaourt ? `yaourt -Syu` seems to do the same as `pacman -Syu`, which only care about package in official repository.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can update your system including AUR packages with:

```
yaourt -Syua
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt

Answer (score 3):

If you had read the manual pages:

```
$man yaourt
```

You would have seen an entry like this:

```
-a, --aur
    Also search in AUR database. With -u or --sysupgrade, upgrade aur
    packages that are out of date. With -Qm, display more info about
    foreign package.
```

In fact you'll find many other options in the man pages for things yaourt can do but pacman cannot. 
pacman was built keeping in mind the Arch Way.